# word2vecのdistanceのソート部分（コサイン類似度）アルゴリズムについて

Tags: python, c, word2vec, 自然言語処理

現在word2vecのdistance.cを学習していますが、コサイン類似度計算部がよくわかりません。

[word2vecのdistance.c](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/051324db98614eaed22f)

現在pythonを用いて次のようなコードを書いています。

[自分で書いたpythonコード](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1068397a74ef7bdeedf9)
（このコードを実行する際は、word2vecで270次元のベクトルを作成する必要があります。※オプションで -binary 0 指定の必要あり）

中でも、コサイン類似度を求める部分は次のようになっています。

```
    cos={} # コサイン類似度を格納する辞書型リストの初期化
    queryVec = vocab[query]
    # 全単語について探索する
    for word in vocab.keys():
        tlist = vocab[word]
        i = 0
        # 内積の初期化
        inpro = 0
        # 内積の計算
        for i in range(1,271):
            inpro = queryVec[i] *tlist[i]
        # 内積÷長さ
        cos[word] = inpro / (queryVec[0]*tlist[0])
```

続いてソート部分です。ソート結果は毎回同じ単語の並びになってしまいます。

```
    # 上位N位を初期化
    i = 0
    bestd = {}
    for i in range(0,N):
        bestd[i]=[-1,'']
    count = 0
    # この中から上位N位を選出
    for word in vocab.keys():
        #print word,cos[word]
        a =0
        # 自分と同じ単語以外
        if query != word :
            for a in range(0,N):
                if cos[word] > bestd[a][0] :
                    b = N-1
                    count +=1
                    for b in range(b,a,-1):
                        temp = bestd[b-1]
                        bestd[b] = temp
                    bestd[a] = [word,cos[word]]
                    break
                a+=1
```

結果例（3100さんの訂正後の結果です。input wordにどんな単語を用いても結果はこれになります）

```
please input word >愛

愛
                                          Word       Cosine　distance
```

---

```
20
                                        出産      0.353152
                                           團        0.178738
                                        仙界      0.262659
                                           土        0.295177
                                           園        0.140053
                                     遂げる        -0.178689
                                     シルク        0.286873
```

Comment: 入力ファイルは1行目にファイルの情報、2行目以降にベクトルデータが格納されています。入力ファイルはテキストで読み込める形式です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for i in range(1,271):
        inpro = queryVec[i] *tlist[i]
```

ここ、inproの値が毎回書き換わってますが、内積計算ということなので、加算していかないといけない気がしました。

```
 for i in range(1,271):
        inpro += queryVec[i] *tlist[i]
```

またソートについては

```
max = N
for k,v in sorted(cos.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True):
    if max == 0:
        break
    if query == v:
        continue
    print '%50s\t\t%f' % (k,v)
    max -= 1
```

などとしたほうが処理がスッキリします。（まだ綺麗にする余地はあると思いますが)

Comment: やってみましたところ、コサイン類似度の値は改善され、0.1以上のものばかりになりました。
しかし、出力結果（コサイン類似度の上位）は依然として同じ結果のままでした・・・

Comment: ソート部分のコードも質問部についかしました

Comment: コサイン類似度自体の値は合うようになりましたか？ソートについてはちょっと元のコードがわかりにくかったので、`cos`の値で降順ソートするようにしてみました。

Comment: コサイン類似度の値は正しく表示されました。ソートは全体から上位N位を挿入ソートで求めるアルゴリズムで書いています。

Comment: reverse=T　のTとはなんのことでしょうか

Comment: すみません。Trueです。写し違えました

Comment: すばらしいです。ソートから表示までできました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 良かったです。
データ量が多いときはより効率のよいソートを自前実装してもよいのですが、大抵の場合言語の機能に委ねてしまったほうがコードのメンテナンスも楽になる気がします。`c`では自分で作りこまねばいけない部分も、`python`などの軽量言語ではある程度標準ライブラリなどで提供されていますので、ご活用されると良いかもです。